# Check if function will result in error before executing

Tags: discord.js

I have this discord bot I have been playing around with. Since I constantly am trying things, I decided to do a command-command, which I would call by doing `!cmd (message.channel or whatever)`. However, due me being bad at typing and forgetting to do things like declare variables, the commands often result in (obvious) errors. Is there a way to check if the function will result in an error? My current code is this:

```
if(splitMessage[0] === '!cmd'){
//splitMessage is the variable that splits !cmd from the rest (no problems with it yet)
        var c = message.content.split(/ (.+)/)[1];
        eval(c);
}
```

My eventual goal is something like

```
if(splitMessage[0] === '!cmd'){
    var c = message.content.split(/ (.+)/)[1];
    if(eval(c) == error){
        eval(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your function ? if you wants to see if you got an error the best way is still to execute you function.

Comment: yeah I get the error (it always is a dumb one) but then the bot crashes and I don't want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(splitMessage[0] === '!cmd'){
    var c = message.content.split(/ (.+)/)[1];
    try {
        eval(c);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('There is an error!')
    }
}
```

Modifying a code in runtime is so bad though.